# Cannot update UI on main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, cllocationmanager

I am trying to update the text in a `UILabel` but I can't get it to change.

The update is triggered by one of two buttons. The first button works fine, here is its event handler:

```
- (void)laterPressedForLocation {
    self.locationLabel.text = @"Location off";
    // works as expected...
}
```

The second button will not update the text no matter what I try, here is its event handler:

```
// ask for location permission....
- (void)acceptPressedForLocation {
    _clLocManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _clLocManager.delegate = self;
   if ([_clLocManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
       [_clLocManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

// called when location permissions change
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      self.locationLabel.text = @"Location permission updated";
      // always runs, but does not work
   });
}
```

If I put a break point or a `NSLog` statement where the text change is, I see that the code is executed and the block completes - but the text never actually changes.

Note that this `UILabel` isn't changed anywhere else in the code.

How can I force the UI to update?

I tried delaying the update like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateText) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01f];
```

but still nothing happens.

**UPDATE**

I found another similar case so I know it has nothing to do with the location manager - something is blocking `self` from performing updates..

The parent view has a button which calls `removeFromSuperview` on the view with the stubborn UILabel, and when I push that button, nothing happens and the UIView does not go anywhere. All my other views are still working fine - what would cause one UIView to stop responding to UI updates?

Comment: My guess is that at the time that code is Called, locationLabel is nil.

Comment: no its reused, it is displaying something else and I want to change it

Comment: Humor me. Put a breakpoint in the code that updates the label and check it when it hits the breakpoint to see if it's nil.

Comment: just did. it exists

Comment: the [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/) has different callback methods... where does the method `-authorizationStatusChanged:` actually come from?

Comment: oh its called by the delegate method, I've updated my code and the OP to make the call more direct, and seeing same problem

Comment: A couple questions:  1) what is `self`?  2) If you add the line `NSLog(@"%p", self.locationLabel);` into both handlers (the second one should go inside the `dispatch_async()` call), do they show the same address (i.e. they're actually the same label)?  3) If they're the same, though it's a bit hacky, it would at least let you verify that you can apply a change, does adding in a call to `[self.locationLabel setNeedsDisplay];`, right after you assign the value in the authorization status change handler, change anything?

Comment: 1) self is UIView subclass (just a wrapper for other views) 2) checked, they are the same object 3) added the code, confirmed it ran, but saw no changes

Comment: Discovered some new details that might be useful, check out my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.. The UIView initialization code was getting triggered a second time and a duplicate view was in front of the one I was changing, making it appear that the changes had no effect.